# Expressing tensor product in terms of symmetric product and exterior product

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space. Is there a way to express $T_n(V)$ (n-fold tensor of $V$) in terms of symmetric products $Sym_i(V)$ and exterior products $\Lambda^j(V)$ ?

Maybe this is not a very well-defined question, but I just want to know the results and references. As commented below, there seems to be a way of expressing $T_n(V)$ as direct sums.

Comment: What do you mean by "express"? Do you want a direct sum of tensor products of $\operatorname{Sym}^i\left(V\right)$'s and $\Lambda^j \left(V\right)$'s? In that case, no, there is no such way for $n = 3$. If you allow "direct differences" (formally understood), then yes, you can do it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Do you know any references for such results?

Comment: Consider all the vector spaces as representations of $\operatorname{GL}\left(V\right)$, and pass to their characters. Thus you want to write the symmetric function $h_1^n$ (which is the character of $T_n\left(V\right)$) as an $\mathbb{N}$-linear combination of $h_i$'s and $e_j$'s (which are the characters of $\operatorname{Sym}^i\left(V\right)$ and $\Lambda^j\left(V\right)$). For degree reason, this means $h_3$ and $e_3$. But that's impossible.

Comment: OK, my first comment was garbled. Of course, you have to forbid tensor products. Also, you cannot help yourself with plethysms (= things like $\operatorname{Sym}^i\left(\Lambda^j\left(V\right)\right)$), since the degree of $T_3\left(V\right)$ is $3$, which is prime.

Comment: OK, I'm seeing that you can use direct sums inside your functors, too (like $\Lambda^3\left(V\otimes V\otimes V\right)$). These are not accounted for by my argument at all.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks anyway... this seems to be much more complicated than I thought before

Comment: Schur-Weyl duality expresses $V^{\otimes n}$, as a representation of $GL(V)$ (and in fact as a functor in $V$), as a direct sum of what are called Schur functors. The symmetric and exterior powers are two of these but there are more as soon as $n \ge 3$.